# What is needed to add an paperprint-like effect to photos in python?

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I want to transform photos in python to look like this:

[image: a paper printed-like pic]
taken from [doctype.com](http://doctype.com)

I will use it in django, PIL is installed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a bit better luck with ImageMagick when it comes to more complex transformations.  You would have to install it separately and though there is a python library it doesn't appear well documented so I've just used command line calls.

Here is a good [tutorial on warping image](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/warping/): 
And [another tutorial on general use](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/)

The drop shadow is probably just a second image which is composited with the first image.

Answer (score 3):

This is a combination of several subtle effects. It starts by a nonlinear deformation, and then a tasteful drop shadow is added. There's also a small border. I'd start by drawing one straight, vertical line on the above picture, and then seeing how you would transform to that from the original picture. Then, apply that transformation to the whole photo, add some drop shadow, and figure out what else is left...